# Finding PV Farms for inspection using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, spatial-join, address

I have over 100 sites (polygons that surround PV farms) loaded in ArcMap that I'd like to drive to throughout the state of Massachusetts for inspection. Problem is, they dont have addresses. I added a address layer to the map.

Is there a way to get the addresses (or closest to) of the polygons so I can plug them in my phone and drive to?

Ultimately, what I am attempting to do is identify all of the solar farms in the state and drive to them for inspection.

I really would like to create an attribute table of the locations with spatial data and additional fields that are specific to the site.

[image: Screenshot of the polygons that represent the outline of the solar field, and the point are from the address layer]

Comment: Spatial join http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000 polygon to points, use the attribute of the nearest point; note intersecting is *nearest*, if there are multiple points in a polygon then the *nearest* is arbitrarily chosen.

Comment: The term you're looking for is [reverse geocoding](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/geocoding-toolbox/reverse-geocode.htm).

Comment: Ty dbaston. The Address layer does not have an attribute table to join with the polygon but when I use the information icon there is a ton of data from a point.

Comment: Ty both for your contributions. I have found that my original polygons where the PV sites are located don't contain any spatial data (they are converted from GE KML files). Would it be best to manually place points where the polygons are in a new map? I have also reworded the problem, thinking of just re-posting it in a new way to better get across what it is I am trying to accomplish. What do you guys think?

Comment: It is fine to ask new questions as long as each is sufficiently focused.  Please review http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Comment: Convert the polygons to points.  Reproject the points to the Web Mercator CRS.  Convert the resulting points to KML in ArcGIS.  Add the KML to a Google Map that you create.  Use the Google map to navigate to your sites.